# Deleting an object after disconnection in socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm new to NodeJS, & I want to create a multiplayer using socket.io. Here is the  snippet:

```
io.on("connection", function(socket){

players.push(socket);    

if(players.length === 2){
    console.log("2 players connected");

     var n = matches.length;
     matches[n] = new Match(poll,matches,n).init();



}
```

So, it's  simple, when there are 2 players (2 sockets) in the array players, I create a new Match with the players in the array, and store it in matches array, but my concern comes here, I need the object Match to be deleted whenever  a player (or both of them) disconnects from the Match, I know JavaScript uses garbage collection, but I made the following test, I managed to delete the Match from the array matches, but the Match was still alive, I suspect it was because  both of players's connection were alive, but if both of players disconnects can I be sure that the object Match is not stored somewhere in memory?

This is how Match looks by now:

```
function   Match(players, matches, id) {
this.playerOne =  players[0];
this.playerTwo =  players[1];
this.board = [["0","0","0"],["0","0","0"],["0","0","0"]];
this.id = id;
this.matches = matches;
}


Match.prototype.init = function(){


        console.log("new game!");
        var that = this;    
        this.playerOne.on("moved", function(c){
            console.log("player one moved")
            that.playerTwo.emit("opponent-moved",c);

        });

        this.playerTwo.on("moved", function(c){
            console.log("player two moved")
            that.playerOne.emit("opponent-moved",c);

        });

        this.playerOne.on("disconnect",function(){
            console.log("Player one disconnected");
            // that.io.emit("delete", that.id);
            that.matches.splice(that.id,1);

        });

    }
```

Comment: All references to the match would have to be removed for it to get garbage collection (which also doesn't happen instantly). What does `init` look like?

Comment: @CoryDanielson In init i add a couple of listeners for both players.

Comment: You'd have to unbind the listeners from both players and remove the match from the array. Then it'd get cleaned up. Does Match have a close method to undo what init does?

Comment: @CoryDanielson No, i don't have a close method, but it seems like i need one, how  it's the best way to undo what init does ?

Comment: Please show us the code for the `Match()` object.  If it has event listeners for the socket, then it will stay alive as long as the socket stays alive.

Comment: You'd have to manually remove the listeners that you set up inside of init.

Comment: What library are you using for your pubsub/listeners? It will have an easy way to remove event listeners.

Comment: @jfriend00 that's how Match() looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a `Match` object to get garbage collected, there has to be no more references to it anywhere in your page.  From what you've disclosed of your code, that means the following:

1. The `Match` object has to be removed from your `matches` array.
2. The `Match` object has to remove all event handlers on the two sockets or the two sockets have to no longer have any references to them and be disconnected.  If the sockets are still alive and the event handlers are not removed, then the `Match` objects are still alive and operating even if you remove them from your array.
3. Any other code that has a reference to the `Match` objects has to clear or delete that reference (depending upon what type of reference it is).

Then, once the garbage collector determines that a given `Match` object is no longer reachable by any code or event handlers, the garbage collector will clean them up.